# How to Extract URLs from HYPERLINK in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some words containing url/hyperlink, Example [RTU](http://www.rtu.ac.in) [SBCET](https://www.sbss.ac.in)

I want to extract url from the word RTU and SBCET in the google sheets. But, I am not able to find any inbuilt function to extract urls from word. I used some custom functions obtained from internet such as GetURL, extractHyperlinks etc. to get urls but the problem is that, while running code an error is occured 'Error    Attempted to execute GETLINKmenu, but it was deleted.' and the code is not executing. I used various codes from the internet but the problem is same. so kindly help me to extract urls. Example of code which i have used.

```
const extractHyperlinksInSheet = () => {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  const hyperlinks = [];

  const spreadsheedId = ss.getId();
  const sheetName = sheet.getName();

  const getRange = (row, col) => {
    const address = sheet.getRange(row + 1, col + 1).getA1Notation();
    return `${sheetName}!${address}`;
  };

  const getHyperlink = (rowIndex, colIndex) => {
    const { sheets } = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheedId, {
      ranges: [getRange(rowIndex, colIndex)],
      fields: 'sheets(data(rowData(values(formattedValue,hyperlink))))',
    });
    const [{ formattedValue, hyperlink }] = sheets[0].data[0].rowData[0].values;
    hyperlinks.push({ rowIndex, colIndex, formattedValue, hyperlink });
  };

  sheet
    .getDataRange()
    .getFormulas()
    .forEach((dataRow, rowIndex) => {
      dataRow.forEach((cellValue, colIndex) => {
        if (/=HYPERLINK/i.test(cellValue)) {
          getHyperlink(rowIndex, colIndex);
        }
      });
    });

  Logger.log(hyperlinks);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the hyperlinks set to the texts of `RTU` and `SBCET` using Google Apps Script.

I thought that in this case, it might not be required to use Sheets API. I thought that even RichText could be used to achieve your goal. When this is reflected in a sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

```js
const extractHyperlinksInSheet = () => {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const hyperlinks = sheet.getDataRange().getRichTextValues().reduce((ar, r) => {
    r.forEach(c =>
      c.getRuns().forEach(e => {
        if (["RTU", "SBCET"].includes(e.getText().trim().toUpperCase())) {
          ar.push(e.getLinkUrl());
        }
      })
    );
    return ar;
  }, []);
  console.log(hyperlinks);
}
```

- When this script is run, the hyperlinks set to the texts of `RTU` and `SBCET` in the active sheet are retrieved.

#### References:

- [getRichTextValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getRichTextValues())
- [Class RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

### Added 1:

From the following reply,

> If the word RTU is contained in cell M1, and SBCET is contained in cell M2 or any other word in cell M3 then my need is to retrieve the URL in cell N1 and N2 or somewhere else.

I understood your expected result as follows.

- You want to retrieve the URLs from the words except for the words `RTU` and `SBCET`.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const extractHyperlinksInSheet = () => {
  const excludeWords = ["RTU", "SBCET"];
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const hyperlinks = sheet.getDataRange().getRichTextValues().reduce((ar, r) => {
    r.forEach(c =>
      c.getRuns().forEach(e => {
        const url = e.getLinkUrl();
        const v = e.getText().trim().toUpperCase();
        if (url && !excludeWords.includes(v)) {
          ar.push(url);
        }
      })
    );
    return ar;
  }, []);
  console.log(hyperlinks);
}
```

- When this script is run, the URLs from the words except for the words `RTU` and `SBCET` are retrieved.

### Added 2:

From your following reply,

> under consolidate tab, I have to retrieve url/hyperlink in the cell F3:F

I understand that you want to retrieve the hyperlinks from cells "B5:B" and put the retrieved hyperlinks to cells "F5:F". In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const extractHyperlinksInSheet = () => {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Consolidate");
  const hyperlinks = sheet.getRange("B3:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getRichTextValues().map(([c]) => [c.getLinkUrl() || null]);
  sheet.getRange(3, 6, hyperlinks.length).setValues(hyperlinks);
}
```

- If you want to retrieve the hyperlinks from "B5:B", please modify from `"B3:B"` to `"B5:B" and from` getRange(3, 6, hyperlinks.length)`to`getRange(5, 6, hyperlinks.length)`.
- This sample script is for your provide Spreadsheet. If you change the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

Comment: The URL contains the word RTU and SBCET is retrieved in the execution log as Info [ 'http://www.rtu.ac.in/', 'https://www.sbss.ac.in/' ]. But my need is to retrieve the URL within the sheet and also for different words.

Comment: @Ranjan Kumar Singh Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience and my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `But my need is to retrieve the URL within the sheet and also for different words.`. In your question, you say `I want to extract url from the word RTU and SBCET in the google sheets.`. My answer achieves this. If my understanding is not correct, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about the details of your expected result? By this, I would like to confirm it. For example, you want to retrieve all hyperlinks in a sheet on a Google Spreadsheet?

Comment: Sir, actually I am apologizing for my poor English skills. If the word RTU is contained in cell M1, and SBCET is contained in cell M2 or any other word in cell M3 then my need is to retrieve the URL in cell N1 and N2 or somewhere else.

Comment: @Ranjan Kumar Singh Thank you for replying. In your situation, you want to retrieve the URLs from the words except for the words `RTU` and `SBCET`. Is my understanding correct? Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand it, I added one more sample script to my answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your expected result, I apologize again.

Comment: Sir, the script runs within the Apps Script of Google Sheets as "7:11:38 PM Notice Execution started
7:12:02 PM Info Logging output too large. Truncating output. " and retrieved output for some words.  But I required the retrieved URL in the Google Sheet Spreadsheet cell.  And also required all words which entered in the spreadsheet.

Comment: Example : word RTU in cell M1, then my expected result is www.rtu.ac.in the cell N1.

Comment: @Ranjan Kumar Singh Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. From your reply, I cannot understand your actual expected result. But, I would like to support you. But, I couldn't notice `But I required the retrieved URL in the Google Sheet Spreadsheet cell. And also required all words which entered in the spreadsheet.` from your question. And, I cannot imagine your expected result from your reply and your showing script. I deeply apologize for my very poor English skill again.

Comment: @Ranjan Kumar Singh So, in order to correctly understand your actual question, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet and the sample values or situation you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it. I think that when I can correctly understand your actual question, I can propose a script for achieving it. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Sir, the link of spreadsheet is https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iz1qMwktuRfviyNdD0HG_hBDQMSQ3Vhn7SAmTw6xtF8/edit?usp=drivesdk , under consolidate tab, I have to retrieve url/hyperlink in the cell F3:F

Comment: @Ranjan Kumar Singh Thank you for replying. From your provided Spreadsheet, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it.

Comment: Sir, thank you so much for making such an effort. But, unfortunately, I am not able to retrieve/extract url using the formula/script. I have copied and pasted the hyperlink in cells F3 and F4. I want to retrieve all values(B3:B) using a formula/script.

Comment: @Ranjan Kumar Singh Thank you for replying. About `But, unfortunately, I am not able to retrieve/extract url using the formula/script. I have copied and pasted the hyperlink in cells F3 and F4. I want to retrieve all values(B3:B) using a formula/script.`, my added script retrieves URLs from B3:B and the retrieved URLs are put into F3:F. So, I cannot understand what you want to do. As I have already asked, can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect? I deeply apologize for my very very poor English skill again. Can you cooperate to resolve your actual question?

Comment: Yes, The sample script provided by you is perfectly working. 


const extractHyperlinksInSheet = () => {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Consolidate");
  const hyperlinks = sheet.getRange("B3:B" + sheet.getLastRow()).getRichTextValues().map(([c]) => [c.getLinkUrl() || null]);
  sheet.getRange(3, 6, hyperlinks.length).setValues(hyperlinks);
}